# Custom slide library feature for SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, slidelibrary

My customer is looking for the custom slide library feature for SharePoint 2013. Since the original feature (SP 2010) is being deprecated what would be the level of effort to recreate it as a custom solution?
I would highly appreciate any feedback, suggestion or guidance on how to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

This feature is discontinued, but as always you can still create it using a direct link

```
http://siteurl/_layouts/15/slnew.aspx?FeatureId={0be49fe9-9bc9-409d-abf9-702753bd878d}&ListTemplate=2100
```

Note - I have no idea how long this hidden feature will be there. But you can use this as an immediate solution till you create custom solution.

Answer (score 2):

What we are doing is utilizing an html page and xps documents.

We created an html page, non-SharePoint page that is imported into SharePoint.  We have links (buttons) across the top and bottom that are hyperlinked to XPS documents.

We save each PPT slide(s) as an XPS document (Office 2013).

When you click on a link, the respective office's XPS document is rendered in the page.

A couple of benefits, you can hyperlink and open other types of documents as well(if needed)  without the clunkiness of having to leave a presentation.  It works fine with multiple page PPT/XPS documents.

Answer (score 1):

If you really have the need to customize the library, it can be prepared using JavaScript components, just by looking at the information in the library.
 And it's not very time consuming.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Due to [design limitation](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Discontinued-features-and-modified-functionality-in-Microsoft-SharePoint-2013-bbbb0815-2538-4f1d-b647-1f7f6d508c93#__toc382936212) in SharePoint 2013 this feature is depreciated.even you access the feature by url hack but looks like it is not worth.

As per MSFT as workaround:
Users are still able to insert slides from PowerPoint files ([see Copy and reuse slides from another presentation file.](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/copy-and-reuse-slides-from-another-presentation-file-ha102749659.aspx))

you can use the 3rd party tools i.e from [DYNAPOINT](http://dynapointdesign.com/products.html)